# How do I deal with a nullable TimeSpan column in a Kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have defined the following column for a nullable TimeSpan value in a Kendo grid:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.StartTime).Width(70).ClientTemplate("<input type='textbox' name='StartTime' value='<#= StartTime.Hours #>:<#= StartTime.Minutes #>' />");
```

However, when `StartTime` is null, I get the client side error "Cannot read property 'Hours' of null".

Is there a standard way of dealing with things like this, or must I just hack something out?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a default value you'd like to use, you can use that. For example...

```
<#= (StartTime ?? DateTime.Now).Hours #>
```

Or another way to do it would be to use an if-expression:

```
<#= StartTime == null ? 3 : StartTime.Hours #>
```

The other thing you could do is simply check to see if StartTime is null and leave out the line altogether. That would be done with the `HasValue` property of Nullable:

```
if(StartTime.HasValue)
{
    // Code
}
```